# Excel move tab when you go to another tab

Tags: excel, tabs, move

This one is hard to explain but I would like to move a summary tab to the left of the active tab. I attached a GIF on what I mean, as you can see the red tab moves to the left of the tab I click. Any idea on how this is done?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAtoZ.gif

Answer (score 0):

Insert this code in every sheet Code (except the "Roll-up" sheet)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim WsActive As Worksheet
    
    On Error GoTo Errorhandler
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Roll-up")
    Set WsActive = ActiveSheet
   
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ws.Move Before:=ActiveSheet
    WsActive.Activate
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    Exit Sub
Errorhandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Save your workbook as .xlsm file

This is called Worksheet event. The macro gets triggered by activating the worksheet where the code lies.

We need to switch off these events before activating this sheet otherwise the macro will go in loops and in some cases Excel might crash.

After the sheet is activated you have to enable the events again (enableevents = true). Otherwise it will not work next time.

If there is an error the events need to get set to true in the errorhandler.
If the macro for some reasons (stopping it manually)  will not run the enableevents=true, then no events are possible, until Excel is closed and reopened or you run the code `Application.EnableEvents = True` somehow.

Comment: This works but whenever I click a tab it goes to the rollup tab. So the only tab I could view is the rollup tab.

Comment: Hello Prema, I tried the updated code and it does not do anything. I added it to all my tabs and when I click any tabs it doesn't do anything. I commented out the error handler and the tabs moved but then Excel crashed. Any ideas?

Comment: @NightSlasher Now i added the enableevents= false to your code and made som more explenaitions in the answer. It should work now.
Excel might chrash again if you open it and try to change the code. Please open VBA windwo ALT+F11, there on the left you can double click on the sheets and update the code. You also could insert this macro below in a new module or in a sheet code view and run it manually to turn off the events. Then changing the macros in the sheets. After that. turning on the events again (enableevents=true). or run the provided macro.

Comment: @NightSlasher 
'Sub StopEvents()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
End Sub'